# Read output in terminal and compare it with a string

Tags: c++, linux, bash, ubuntu

How to check whether a program like 'fortune' is already installed programatically?
This is my code:

```
if(choice==1)
{
    cout<<"Need to Install program first? [y/n]: ?"<<endl;
    cin>>yn;
    if(yn=='y' || yn=='Y')
    {
            cout<<"Installing..."<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter password if asks:"<<endl;
            system(" sleep 2");
            system("sudo apt-get install fortune");


    }
```

I have tried this, but couldn't get what I want.

```
dpkg-query -1W fortune  2>&1 |  read line ; do echo $line | say ; done
```

UPDATE: I have solved this long back and thanks to @John Zwinck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if a program like `fortune` is installed, you can simply check if it exists!

```
if (access("/usr/bin/fortune", R_OK | X_OK) == 0)
    printf("we have good fortune\n");
```

If you have a program which should be somewhere in `$PATH` but you don't know where, you could try to run it:

```
if (system("fortune --help") != -1)
    printf("we have good fortune\n");
```